# IOS6 Enable WeiBo

Tags: ios, ios6, social-networking, weibo

I am using Social Framework to post to WeiBo but i couldn't find WeiBo under phone's setting.
I only found facebook and twitter. Any idea how to enable WeiBo on your device?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to enable the Chinese keyboard in the Settings app. Specifically:

`Settings -> General -> Keyboard -> International Keyboards -> Add New Keyboard...`

There are a number of Chinese options, I believe any of them should work but please correct me if I'm wrong.